Quarkus Hibernate ignoring import.sql when running inside docker
I have the problem that when I run quarkus in a container it does not use the import.sql that is present. I tried every way I could think of to configure it. As stated in the documentation under the config properties it should use the import.sql if the profile is set to dev.
Is anybody able to help here?
I tried as exaplained in the docs. When running normally from the commandline and not in a container the debug log shows that the property for hibernate to use the import.sql is set correctly. Inside the container it is left blank.

So basically this is possible using %prod.quarkus.hibernate-orm.sql-load-script=import.sql
But this kinda defeats the purpose of dev/test/prod profiles that have different configs. I want to be able to use my container when testing as well as in prod

I think you're after this feature: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/21866
See in particular: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/21866#issuecomment-1046997899

Damn I hoped I was just too stupid to find something. But if it is not implemented I am unable to find it. Thank you.
